# Is there something wrong with this XML/PHP Code for Tumblr to Website?

Tags: php, xml, web, linker, tumblr

I am trying to link a tumblr feed to a website.  I found this code (As you can see, something must be broken with it as it doesnt even format correctly in this post):

```
    <?php
$request_url = “http://thewalkingtree.tumblr.com/api/read?type=post&start=0&num=1”;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$title = $xml->posts->post->{‘regular-title’};
$post = $xml->posts->post->{‘regular-body’};
$link = $xml->posts->post[‘url’];
$small_post = substr($post,0,320);
echo ‘<h1>’.$title.’</h1>’;
echo ‘<p>’.$small_post.’</p>’;
echo “…”;
echo “</br><a target=frame2 href=’”.$link.”’>Read More</a>”; 
?>

And i inserted the tumblr link that I will be using.  When I try to preview my HTML, i get a bunch of messed up code that reads as follows:

posts->post->{'regular-title'}; $post = $xml->posts->post->{'regular-body'}; $link = $xml->posts->post['url']; $small_post = substr($post,0,320); echo '
'.$title.'

'; echo '
'.$small_post.'

'; echo "…"; echo "Read More"; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is PHP, not HTML. You need to process it with a PHP parser before delivering it to a web browser.

… it should also be rewritten so it can cache the remote data, and escape special characters before injecting the data into an HTML document.